# Retrieve Last n Rows Starting From Last Row with Specified Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a sample table below:

```
Id  Action  Qty
1   Start   3
2   Give    2
3   Take    1
...
X   Start   8
X+1 Give    5
X+2 Take    3
```

Using EF, I would like to retrieve the last number of rows starting from last row where Action="Start".

With the sample table above, the result should be:

```
Id  Action  Qty
X   Start   8
X+1 Give    5
X+2 Take    3
```

The following code will only work if there are 2 rows after the last Action="Start" row which is not always the case:

```
var result = db.Sample.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).Take(3); // not always 3
```

Comment: Are the actions in another table? If so you can do `.Take(db.Actions.Count())` to take the right amount of rows.

Comment: @dcg Action is a column in the same table.

Comment: Then you could do something like `db.Sample.Select(x=>x.Action).Distinct().Count()` and use that number in the `Take`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by, then find the max of `Start`, then get all Id's greater than or equal to max of `Start`.  Actually, grouping is not necessary if your data is sorted.

```
var maxIdOfStart = collection
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)
    .First(x => x.Action == "Start");

var lastNOfStart = collection
    .Where(x => x.Id >= maxIdOfStart.Id);
```

Comment: I would remove the `group` part from your answer.